# Does the word of an attachment map for some cell on a CW complex correspond to the cellular boundary map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm in the middle of reading Hatcher, Chapter 2.2. The definition he gives for the boundary map for cellular homology of a CW complex $X$ is for some $n$-cell, $e^n_\alpha$, $d_n(e^n_\alpha) = \sum_\beta d_{ab}e_{b}^{n-1}$ where $\beta$ ranges through all adjacent $n-1$ cells and $d_{ab}$ is the degree of the quotient map of the attachment map $\partial(e^n_\alpha) \to X^{n-1}/(X^{n-1} - e^{n-1}_\beta)$, which is a map between spheres. My question is that if the attachment map is given as a word of $n-1$-cells for each of the $n$-cells we attach, is the cellular boundary of each $n$-cell its corresponding word?

I think the answer is yes because I think the degree of the quotient map of the attachment map associated to $\beta$ seems to be the total number of times the cell for $\beta$ shows up in the word. However, I'm not sure how to justify this answer.

Comment: How do you want to specify the attaching map on an $n$-cell by a word of $(n-1)$-cells? I'm guessing you're thinking of the case $n=2$ but this cannot be generalised to arbitrary $n$.

Comment: Oh. I should have realized. In that case is there a way to compute the boundary of an n-cell in the vein of computing the boundary in the n-simplex? And does this boundary coincide with the cellular homolgical boundary operator?